# Submitting to database from modal view

Tags: php, mysql, submit, modal-dialog, form-submit

I have a file, let`s name it dashboard.php, in this file i load a modal window and trough this window i want to submit a form and the form action is also written in this dashboard.php file. is this possible? i am acutally trying it this way, but it s not working:

dashboard:php

```
<?php   $modal_gerade_geschlossen = $_POST['abgespeichert'];
    if ($modal_gerade_geschlossen == 1){
    $neue_addy = $_POST['neue_addy']; 
    $benach_ja_nein = $_POST['benach_ja_nein'];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO mitglieder (email,benachrichtigung)VALUES('$neue_addy','$benach_ja_nein')");
    }
?>

<div class="modal-body" style="height:194px">
          <div>
      <form name="losgehts" method="post" action="../dashboard.php"> 
        <div style="float:left">
            <input name="neue_addy" style="width:270px" type="text"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <select name="benach_ja_nein" >
            <option>ja</option>
            <option>nein</option>
        </select>
      </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="abgespeichert" value="1"/>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Schließen</button>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Speichern"/>
      </form>
          </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what are you getting? some error or?

Comment: after i clicked submit, the modal is trying to close itself but then it stucks while reloading the page